# support of dlopen flag RTLD_GLOBAL

Tags: android-ndk

I load a shared object `mylib.so` containing a function named `foo1` using

```
void* pHandleLocal = dlopen( "mylib.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL );
```

I try to look up for the symbol

```
void* pSymbol = dlsym( pHandleLocal, "foo1" );
```

which works fine. 
After that I try to lookup the symbol in the global scope of the main program.

```
void* pHandleGlobal = dlopen( NULL, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL );
void* pSymbolGlobal = dlsym( pHandleGlobal, "foo1" );
```

The symbol is not found (On Linux both symbol addresses were equal). Isn't the flag RTLD_GLOBAL supported by the android dlopen implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching symbol in already loaded library or running program 
need not use dlopen there special pseudo-handles for this RTLD_DEFAULT, try this

void* pSymbolGlobal = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT , "foo1");

refer [dlsym](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym) man page for more info